# Castle Windsor ArrayResolver ServiceOverrides Not Respected

Tags: castle-windsor

When using the ArrayResolver, if I register multiple dependencies that implement the same interface and I have registered classes that depend on an array of these dependencies, one would expect ServiceOverrides to be respected and allow control over which dependencies are injected into the contructors. Instead, I have seen and written tests that show every dependency is injected into the registered classes contructors.

```
using System.Linq;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.SpecializedResolvers;
using Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration;
using Castle.Windsor;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ServiceFramework.UnitTests
{
    public class ArrayResolver_ServiceOverridesNotRespected
    {
        private class TestInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
        {
            public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
            {
                container.Register(
                    Component.For<IDependency>().ImplementedBy<Foo>().Named("foo"),
                    Component.For<IDependency>().ImplementedBy<Bar>().Named("bar"),
                    Component.For<IDependency>().ImplementedBy<Baz>().Named("baz"),
                    Component.For<IDependOnArray>().ImplementedBy<DependsOnArray>().Named("InjectAll"),
                    Component.For<IDependOnArray>().ImplementedBy<DependsOnArray>().Named("InjectFooOnly").ServiceOverrides(
                        ServiceOverride.ForKey("steps").Eq(new[] {"foo"})),
                    Component.For<IDependOnArray>().ImplementedBy<DependsOnArray>().Named("InjectFooAndBarOnly").ServiceOverrides(
                        ServiceOverride.ForKey("steps").Eq(new[] {"foo", "bar"})));
            }
        }

        public interface IDependency
        {
        }

        public class Foo : IDependency
        {
        }

        public class Bar : IDependency
        {
        }

        public class Baz : IDependency
        {
        }

        public interface IDependOnArray
        {
            IDependency[] GetDependencies();
        }

        public class DependsOnArray : IDependOnArray
        {
            private readonly IDependency[] _steps;
            public DependsOnArray(IDependency[] steps)
            {
                _steps = steps;
            }

            public IDependency[] GetDependencies()
            {
                return _steps;
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void InjectFooOnly_WithoutArrayResolver()
        {
            using (var container = new WindsorContainer())
            {
                container.Install(new TestInstaller());
                var fooItemTest = container.Resolve<IDependOnArray>("InjectFooOnly");
                var dependencies = fooItemTest.GetDependencies().Select(d => d.GetType()).ToList();
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Count.EqualTo(1));
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Member(typeof(Foo)));
            }
        }

        [Test]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(AssertionException))]
        public void InjectFooOnly_WithArrayResolver()
        {
            using (var container = new WindsorContainer())
            {
                container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel, true));
                container.Install(new TestInstaller());
                var fooItemTest = container.Resolve<IDependOnArray>("InjectFooOnly");
                var dependencies = fooItemTest.GetDependencies().Select(d => d.GetType()).ToList();
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Count.EqualTo(1));
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Member(typeof(Foo)));
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void InjectFooAndBarOnly_WithoutArrayResolver()
        {
            using (var container = new WindsorContainer())
            {
                container.Install(new TestInstaller());
                var fooItemTest = container.Resolve<IDependOnArray>("InjectFooAndBarOnly");
                var dependencies = fooItemTest.GetDependencies().Select(d => d.GetType()).ToList();
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Count.EqualTo(2));
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Member(typeof(Foo)));
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Member(typeof(Bar)));
            }
        }

        [Test]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(AssertionException))]
        public void InjectFooAndBarOnly_WithArrayResolver()
        {
            using (var container = new WindsorContainer())
            {
                container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel, true));
                container.Install(new TestInstaller());
                var fooItemTest = container.Resolve<IDependOnArray>("InjectFooAndBarOnly");
                var dependencies = fooItemTest.GetDependencies().Select(d => d.GetType()).ToList();
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Count.EqualTo(2));
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Member(typeof(Foo)));
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Member(typeof(Bar)));
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void InjectAll()
        {
            using (var container = new WindsorContainer())
            {
                container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel, true));
                container.Install(new TestInstaller());
                var fooItemTest = container.Resolve<IDependOnArray>("InjectAll");
                var dependencies = fooItemTest.GetDependencies().Select(d => d.GetType()).ToList();
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Count.EqualTo(3));
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Member(typeof(Foo)));
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Member(typeof(Bar)));
                Assert.That(dependencies, Has.Member(typeof(Baz)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The poster is a colleague of mine and we have confirmed that this behavior exists in both Castle Windsor 2.5.0 and 2.5.1, and that the CollectionResolver shows the same behavior.  I also see the same behavior when using the "DependsOn" syntax for specifying the service overrides in 2.5.1.  I'm not sure if this is by design or not, but this certainly seems like non-intuitive behavior.  I would expect that specifying parameters explicitly takes precedence over sub-dependency resolvers.

Comment: Here's the issue in the Castle issuetracker: http://issues.castleproject.org/issue/IOC-240

Answer (score 1):

The issue is now fixed and the fix will be part of the next major version of Windsor.